# SharePoint 2013 app resize via postMessage bug when title bar hidden

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've encountered a bug with iframe postMessage communications when requesting a resize for an app part where Web Part Properties > Appearance > Chrome Type is set to None.

A JavaScript error in the postMessage handler on the host-side that relies on the web part title being present:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById(webPartDivId + '_ChromeTitle').style.cssText = widthCssText;
```

I found this documented here with no offered work-around:

http://yuriburger.net/2013/04/27/errors-resizing-a-sharepoint-2013-app-part-client-web-part/

I've tried overriding the SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler that is added to an app part, but I think the scope doesn't allow it. Or at least I am not sure why, but it's not working yet.

Does anyone know a work-around for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this bug is addressed in the SharePoint Server Update from March 12:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2767999

Answer (score 0):

I would register Script Action on site
with my modified SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler function, in this case i'll call it mod_SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler
and add this

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if(typeof SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler == "undefined")
    return;
  if (typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
    window.removeEventListener('message',SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler);
    window.addEventListener('message', mod_SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler, false);
  }
  else if (typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
    window.detachEvent('onmessage', SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler);
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', mod_SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler);
  }
}, 200);
```

have not tried, but se if it helps.

Comment: Can you please post the content of the method : mod_SPAppIFramePostMsgHandler